# Sonar asking to Make this field final

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following piece of code in my program and I am running SonarQube 5 for code quality check on it after integrating it with Maven.
I am facing this error

> Make this "public static processStatus" field final.
>
> Make this "public static processStatusId" field final

But I don't want to make this as final. Is there any other solution?

```
public abstract class ProcessStatusListPO_ {
    private ProcessStatusListPO_() {
        
    }

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ProcessStatusListPO, String> processStatus ;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ProcessStatusListPO, Long> processStatusId ;
}
```

Comment: Best alternative: don't use global mutable state.

Comment: I tried but got the same error

Comment: If you stopped using global mutable state, you definitely wouldn't get "Make this "public static processStatus" field final.", because you wouldn't have non-final public static fields.

Comment: @AndyTurner, might need to explain what is a `global mutable state` on this case

Comment: As an aside, what's the purpose of having a private constructor in an abstract class? (Unless all of its subclasses are inner classes.)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I'd assume preventing anybody from instantiating it using inheritance (except inner classes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sonar is complaining that you shouldn't use mutable state, but you don't want to follow that advice. Your options thus are: ignore the warning or follow the advice even if you don't want to. Following the advice doesn't mean slapping 'final' in there (as it doesn't make sense in this context), but redesigning your code to be better.

You can [ignore using suppresswarnings already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044642/365237). If you want to follow the advice, you need to redesign your piece of code in a different way.

We don't know your code beyond what you've posted, so we cannot say how exactly you should redesign it. However, doing that is recommended. 
As to why, you can read up on it here: [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148154/126417)

Answer (score -1):

if you assume that variable unique in all context make that

> public static final volatile SingularAttribute processStatus ;

- That way you need instance of the var.
- Or put annotations

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = { "CWE-580" })
```

- that way i'm use.
- if anybody has other solutions more elegant please send us.

Comment: `static final volatile` value? can you explain how'd that make sense?

Comment: In my case, i'm use for configuration to pass same parameters for system, change same times, for example: when use a file *config_system.properties* ready this variables, that properties e-mail connection, local was or will installed system,database configuration, version of the java in use, that way to pass parameter no public a new version system. with that occurrences (make a issue change parameter, that sample reconfigure file properties) It was clear?

Comment: by using final volatile, I am getting error. the error is asking me to either remove final or volatile

Comment: remove volatile, because var final can't change anyway, only use.

Comment: Even this annotation is giving me the same error @SuppressWarnings(value = { "CWE-580" }) and I don't want to change it to final, this will bring error in my application