# Java SonarQube Error "Make public static field final"

Tags: java, sonarqube, final

The following field is declared in my java class:

```
public static int count= 0`;
```

This field will be updated by various methods in various use cases, 
but **SonarQube** shows the error:

> Make this public static "count" field final

If I make it as final I will not be able to update this field. Please let me know how to fix this issue without breaking my use case.

Comment: This link can be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044282/sonar-asking-to-make-this-field-final

Comment: Hi jdow - always a good idea to put sample code in a code block in the text editor to make it clearer. By the way, the SonarQube documentation at https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1444 explains WHY it's a bad idea, but doesn't give an alternative. Best approach is probably to use a singleton that can protect the count property with a controlled interface such as an increment() method, rather than allowing anyone to set the value to anything